Asterisk can not register SIP trunk when install inside Docker
I am building Aterisk inside Docker. I am success to create the trunk, when test the trunk I see it's only send and no receive like below:

Here is the log from my Asterisk:
[2024-04-10 08:29:48] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #18)
[2024-04-10 08:30:08] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #19)
[2024-04-10 08:30:28] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #20)
[2024-04-10 08:30:48] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #21)
[2024-04-10 08:31:08] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #22)
[2024-04-10 08:31:28] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #23)
[2024-04-10 08:31:48] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #24)
[2024-04-10 08:32:08] NOTICE[9390]: chan_sip.c:16046 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '234b80b8@sip.nexmo.com' timed out, trying again (Attempt #25)

It's seem the docker can not connect to internet? I am new with Docker, here is our container detail
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND            CREATED          STATUS                           PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                            NAMES
9f46aab63ab0   tiredofit/freepbx      "/init"            21 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes                    443/tcp, 4445/tcp, 4569/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5060->5060/udp, 5061/tcp, 5161/tcp, 8001/tcp, 8003/tcp, 8008-8009/tcp, 8025/tcp, 10050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5160->5160/udp, 18000-20000/udp, 0.0.0.0:2000->80/tcp   crazy_williamson

Note that my docker were deployed from my server, I can register 2 pjsip extension and make call to eaach other from other network. Only register trunk is failed

Did you try docker run -d tiredofit/freepbx --network host?

if I use --net=host => I can not open FreePBX though localhost. I am not familiar with Asterisk config SIP

@samnoon guy can you help me?

@samnoon I am trying to add --net=host then the trunk can connect now, but the pjsip extension can not register

Hi @famfamfam, you need to check the SIP IP for pjsip extension in that case

@samnoon, hi, can you give me some tutorials? I still not solved this after 1 weeks. I have a server then install docker + install asterisk inside (https://github.com/tiredofit/docker-freepbx/tree/15), can I request your skype for fast chat, or can I make a video call to share screen for your help? I really need your help
